# Present continues or simple in relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, present-continuous

I wrote this sentence

> The node features, which are used to create a condition, are selected from a list **showing the available features**

or

> The node features, which are used to create a condition, are selected from a list, **which shows the available features**

Why?

I myself somehow prefer the second sentence

---

By the way now I think if I start with **the available node features, ...**, I don't need a relative clause. However, I still like to know the possible difference here.

Answer (score 2):

They both are correct, but slightly unusual. I suppose nobody will actually be physically looking at that list, so it is slightly odd to say that the list *shows* those features. It would be much easier and probably more idiomatic to say that those features are selected from *a list **of** the available features*.

> The node features, which are used to create a condition, are selected from a list **of** available features.

This is also a lot shorter, leaving you with a more concise sentence.

---

In this case, there is not really any difference between using the definite (*the*) and indefinite (zero article) article. However, using the zero article might, but not necessarily, imply that the list does not contain **all** of the available features that exist, while the definite articles implies that all of the features are included in the list.

Comment: Thank you, but why *available features* and not *the available features*? However, as I wrote in my update, if I use "available" in the first of sentence I would need neither

Comment: Maybe providing or presenting was better than showing, because I wanted to emphasizes the list only lists the available features.

Comment: If the list contains **all** of the available features, use the definite article. I updated my answer by adding an explanation for the difference between the two articles.